# Plugman framework skips Mac OS X symbolic links

Tags: cordova, cordova-plugins, cordova-cli, plugman

I'm working on this plugin: [com.ios.libgoogleadmobads](http://plugins.cordova.io/#/package/com.ios.libgoogleadmobads), which is a helper plugin for https://github.com/appfeel/admob-google-cordova (com.admob.google cordova admob plugin)

As you can see here: https://github.com/appfeel/google-iosadmobads/tree/master/src/ios/GoogleMobileAds.framework

there are two symbolic lynks. When I try to install the plugin:

```
cordova plugin add com.ios.libgoogleadmobads
```

The links are skipped. Any workaround/solution please?

**UPDATE**

As a workaround I've added a hook to create the links via bash and I've deleted the predefined symbolic links. It is working in MAC, not in other systems. So I'm curious to know why plugman doesn't support symbolik links when installing remote plugins (it works for local plugins).

Idea: Could it be due to tar.gz? Could it be fixed in any way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the end I managed to solve it by changing the dependency tag in https://github.com/appfeel/admob-google-cordova in plugin.xml:

```
<dependency id="com.ios.libgoogleadmobads" url="https://github.com/appfeel/google-iosadmobads"/>
```

For anyone who can be helpful, my conclusion is that any .framework library needed in a cordova or phonegap plugin needs to be placed in a separate repo and refferenced with the url attribute.

See related issue here: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-6092

Answer (score 1):

Modify **plugins/com.ios.libgoogleadmobads/hooks/after_plugin_add/000-create-links.sh**. **ln** in there has an illegal option "-r". I suspect they meant to use the force option "-f"?

Update From:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash


ln -s -r plugins/com.ios.libgoogleadmobads/src/ios/GoogleMobileAds.framework/Versions/A/Headers/ plugins/com.ios.libgoogleadmobads/src/ios/GoogleMobileAds.framework/Headers


ln -s -r plugins/com.ios.libgoogleadmobads/src/ios/GoogleMobileAds.framework/Versions/A/GoogleMobileAds plugins/com.ios.libgoogleadmobads/src/ios/GoogleMobileAds.framework/GoogleMobileAds


ln -s -r plugins/com.ios.libgoogleadmobads/src/ios/GoogleMobileAds.framework/Versions/A/ plugins/com.ios.libgoogleadmobads/src/ios/GoogleMobileAds.framework/Versions/Current
```

To:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash


ln -s -f plugins/com.ios.libgoogleadmobads/src/ios/GoogleMobileAds.framework/Versions/A/Headers/ plugins/com.ios.libgoogleadmobads/src/ios/GoogleMobileAds.framework/Headers


ln -s -f plugins/com.ios.libgoogleadmobads/src/ios/GoogleMobileAds.framework/Versions/A/GoogleMobileAds plugins/com.ios.libgoogleadmobads/src/ios/GoogleMobileAds.framework/GoogleMobileAds


ln -s -f plugins/com.ios.libgoogleadmobads/src/ios/GoogleMobileAds.framework/Versions/A/ plugins/com.ios.libgoogleadmobads/src/ios/GoogleMobileAds.framework/Versions/Current
```

Comment: I've made those modifications in the plugin (I'm the author) in order to workaround the problem. I thought that -r is valid option (at least in my macos is ok). The question is why plugman doesn't support links.

Comment: `ln -r` is supposed to create relative path links (seen in `ln --help` from osx 10.9)

Comment: I had the same issue. Updating this file now it works. Thanks!